# PowerShell: Active Directory: How to create a subfolder only accessible with a particular user in a shared folder

Tags: powershell

I have an Active Directory setup. I have shared a folder on my network.

I want to create subfolders in this shared folder accessible only by a particular user. When others open the shared location, they will see only their own folders.

Example of a share location:

```
\\EC2AMAZ-A3DND5L\MainSharefolder
```

Inside this I want to create folders for each Active Directory user.

Example:

```
MainSharefolder
- username1
- username2
- username3
```

Now example `username1` opens the share location `\\EC2AMAZ-A3DND5L\MainSharefolder` he should see only one folder inside the share location `\\EC2AMAZ-A3DND5L\MainSharefolder`.

I want to do this with PowerShell.

I prefer to do this when I create a new user in Active Directory.